# How to force toString when logging object in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I wonder if it is posible to get "content here" as a response (for example  a log) from this code:

```
function Obj () {
    this.toString = function(){ return "content here" };
}
var obj = new Obj;
console.log(obj);
```

I know I can force it with String(), toString() and ""+obj, but I want to know if there is a way of forcing it from WITHIN the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your edit adding

> I know I can force it with String(), toString() and ""+obj, but I want to know if there is a way of forcing it from WITHIN the object.

...changes the question. The simple answer is "no, you can't do that *within the object*." In order for the `toString` on your object to be called, something needs to say "I want the primitive form of this" (or specifically "I want the string form of this"). `console.log` doesn't do that, it provides richer information than that.

Your putting a `toString` on your object means that any time it's converted to a string, your function will get called, but it doesn't dictate when that happens. You can also use `valueOf`. There's more about this in the spec: [§9.1 - *ToPrimitive*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1), [§8.12.8 - *[[DefaultValue]] (hint)*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8), and [§9.8 - *ToString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8).

But adding `toString` (or `valueOf`) doesn't let you dictate when it happens; you can't, that's just done by the rules of JavaScript or the calling code doing it (explicitly, or implicitly).

---

**Original Answer**:

The simplest way is to use `String` on it:

```
console.log(String(obj));
```

You could add your own method:

```
console.logString = function(s) {
    console.log(String(s));
};
```

---

You **could** probably alter `log`:

```
var old = console.log;
console.log = function(s) {
    var a = Array.prototype.map.call(arguments, function(a) {
        return String(a);
    };
    return old.apply(console, a);
};
```

...but **I would not recommend it**.

Comment: No no, I mean without using String() .toString() or ""+obj

Comment: @user3633687: `log` doesn't do that. That's why I suggested you could add your own method. I suppose you could replace `log`, but **I wouldn't**. (I've added to the answer to show how.)

Comment: Yes, but I wonder if there is a way to force it from between the object itself. For example, how to you get a string from sometag.classList if clasList is clearly an object not a simple property?

Comment: @user3633687: Well, you don't. If you do `x = element.classList` you'll get an object (specifically, a `DOMTokenList`); if you did `x = String(element.classList)`, **then** you'd get a string. In order for the `toString` on your object to be called, something needs to say "I want the primitive form of this" (or specifically "I want the string form of this"). `log` doesn't do that, at least not on most modern browsers. For instance, for me using Chrome, `console.log(document.body.classList)` gives me all sorts of stuff, not just a simple string.

Comment: Great! This is the answer to my question!